# Errors while creating a project in Unity with Newtonsoft and NUnit

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just installed the 2022.1.3f1 version of the unity editor but as soon as I create a new project with the 3D core template, I get errors and the only error message I get is:

```
[15:58:57]
```

I have tried installing the editor with and without the unity hub and still get the same result. Even with other versions of unity, I get similar errors with just the numbers being different. Could somebody help me?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Below is a picture of the error:
[image: Errors]

Comment: _"as soon as I create a new project"_ - a new project?  I can see non-default packages there such as _Newtonsoft_ and _NUnit_.  Try again